# React native Picker not working

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I want to add my items inside array to picker, but after I added the values App crash. What I'm doing wrong in here?

```
<Picker selectedValue={this.state.select}
        onValueChange={(lang) => this.setState({select: loc})}>
        <Picker.Item label={this.state.caseTypeList} value="this.state.caseTypeList[0]" />
</Picker>
```

Comment: `onValueChange={(lang) => this.setState({select: loc})}>` you're providing `lang` as parameter, but setting `loc`. In addition, you should add code to define what `this.state.caseTypeList` contains.

Comment: <Picker
                    selectedValue={this.state.searchText}
                    onValueChange={ (caseTypeList) => (      this.setState({searchText:caseTypeList}) ) }  >
                    { this.state.caseTypeList.map((s, i) => {
                        return <PickerItem
                                 key={i}
                                 value={s}
                                 label={s} />
                     }) }
                </Picker>

Comment: i modified my code but still not showing any values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your modified code you posted in the comments looks closer, but for the onValueChange callback you want to set the searchText to the new value chosen in the picker.

`<Picker selectedValue={this.state.searchText}
         onValueChange={(selectedText) => this.setState({searchText: selectedText})}>
        {this.state.caseTypeList.map((s, i) => {
            return <Picker.Item key={i} value={s} label={s}/>
        })}
</Picker>`

If you're still seeing issue, I would confirm what version of react-native you're on. If you're on any version < 0.20, then that could be the reason your app is crashing when using the Picker. Prior to version 0.20, the only available picker component was PickeriOS.